# Боль. буква / бол. буква

Tags: орфография, сокращения

Как правильно сделать аббревиатуру из словосочетания *большая буква*?

> Боль. буква.

> Бол. буква.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой способ называется графическое сокращение.

• Можно так, как в толковом словаре "Грамоты":
[большой](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9)
**1.** Значительный по величине, длине, ширине, объёму и т. п.; превосходящий по размерам ряд однородных предметов и явлений (противоп.: малый, маленький). ***Б.** город. **Б-ая** река. **Б-ие** полушария головного мозга. **Б-ая** буква* (прописная). *Имеет **б.** вес.*

•• Можно так, как словаре современных географических названий:
[Кавказ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_geo/113/%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%97)
Орографической осью служит ***Бол.** Кавказ* (высшая точка Эльбрус, 5642 м). К С. от ***Бол. К.*** простирается Предкавказье, к Ю. расположены Колхидская (на З.) и Кура-Араксинская низм-сти. Они отделяют Закавказское нагорье, которое включает хребты ***Мал.** Кавказа* и Армянское нагорье.

> **3.** Если перед отсекаемой частью слова стоит мягкий знак, то при сокращении он отсекается. Напр.: *польский — пол., сeльcкий — сел.* [**4.5.3**]

••• Теоретически, если отбросить только окончание, можно и ***больш.***
Для чего вам нужно такое сокращение? Нужно определиться.

> 1. Общепринятые сокращения — употребляются во всех изданиях, кроме детских для нач. чтения, ограниченно — в изданиях худож. лит.
> 2. Специальные сокращения — употребляются в изданиях отраслевой лит. для специалистов, принятые в этой отрасли и понятные подготовленному читателю без расшифровки.
> 3. Индивидуальные сокращения — употребляются только в тексте одного издания, введенные его автором или издателем и так или иначе расшифрованные в нем (в списке сокращений, внутри текста вслед за самим сокращением или перед ним, и в списке и внутри текста). [**4.1.2**]

■ Сокращение в виде ***боль.***? Нет, так точно нельзя!

[Сокращения](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091445.html) (А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова. Справочник издателя и автора)
[Список сокращений](http://gramota.ru/slovari/info/ag/sokr/)